# is there any way I can generate a unique number that is NOT as long as a UUID (GUID)?

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formulas to generate a unique id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744081/formulas-to-generate-a-unique-id)

Basically I need to generate a unique number but I don't want it to be too long, such as a UUID. Something half of that size (if not smaller).

Can anyone think of any ways to do this?

Basically I'm going to have an app which might be in use by multiple people and the app generates files and uploads them to the web server. Those names need to be unique.

I'm not looking to use a database table to keep track of this stuff, by the way.

Comment: What language? What operating system?

Comment: This is so extremely generic that there is no sensible answer except to close it as a duplicate of literally thousands of other "how do I generate a random number?" questions.

Comment: just taking `n` random numbers won't work? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: Is there something like a user id for each user that has permission to upload stuff?

Comment: wouldn't the classic filename.ext, filename(1).ext, filename(2).ext work for you to avoid repeated names? You'll need to first check if the file exist and It's not clear for me if you would be able to do it.

Comment: A GUID is practically unique because you would have to create such a huge number of them before having even a 1% chance of creating a duplicate. As you use less bits, it becomes easier to create duplicates. You should look at the probability table on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a UUID, and only take the first half the string.

If you're concerned about generating duplicate IDs, your options are to make them non-random and auto-increment, or to check for the existence of newly generated IDs:

```
do {
  newId = generateNewId();
} while (idExists(newId));
```

Comment: are you saying that there cannot possibly be 2 of the same half a string of a UUID??

Comment: Of course there can. The odds against it are astronomical, though you're still better off generating a full UUID. If you don't trust the randomness to be uniformly distributed, take every other letter of a full UUID, or just generate your own random string. There are literally thousands of examples of how to do so.

Comment: +1. Side notes: there is no way to have any finite values to be unique due to pigeonhole principle. UUID generation algorithm guarantees (as much as possible) uniqueness for whole value and contains parts generated based on different cafeterias (time/random value,...) - so instead of first part it may be better to hash/XOR portions of UUID to get good random number.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert A 64 bit UUID is 2^64 times as likely to suffer from collisions as a 128 bit UUID. **Significantly** more than "twice as likely". This is like saying "1 in 100 odds are half as good as 1 in 100,000" odds; Halving the number of digits does not half the number of possible combination of those digits. A 127 bit UUID would be twice more likely to produce collisions than a 128 bit UUID.

Comment: All, I'm going to go with half of a UUID and take it from there. I'll be uploading this file to a web service. So in case of "conflict" 2 items having the same name, I'll simply rearrange the letters/numbers to make it unique. (or simply add a letter or number at the end). I will prob never run into this problem but i'll def. have a checker there to do this if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it unique and short go with UUID and use a url shortener.

Answer (score 0):

Piqued my curiosity:

```
// create a 32-bit uid:
    var i = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), (new Random()).Next(0, 12));
// create a 64-bit uid
    var l = BitConverter.ToUInt64(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(), (new Random()).Next(0, 8));
```

Of course the following may be equally applicable because you lose most of the features of a guid when you truncate it, and might as well resort to a random number:

```
l = BitConverter.ToUInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes((new Random()).NextDouble()), 0);
```

... if you're looking for a 64-bit integer.